# How to post array / data structure via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using HTML & JavaScript at the client side, and `NodeJs` as the server side.

I have a form which contains several radio buttons.
When the client click on submit button, I want to send (post) the results to the server.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >

var questionCounter = 0;
var questionId = 0;
var ans = [];

function check(id, result) {                                                                                                                        
   ans[id.substring(1)] = result;                                  
}

function printQueue(question) {     

    questionId++;
    questionCounter++;  
    var radioName="Q"+questionCounter;
    var id = "Q" + questionCounter;                 
    document.write("<p> <b> " + question + " </b> </p>");                                                                                                                       
    document.write ("<input type=\"radio\" id=" + id + " name=" + radioName +
                    " onclick=\"check(this.id, this.value)\" value=\"5\">Very Good<br>");
    document.write ("<input type=\"radio\" id=" + id + " name=" + radioName + 
                        " onclick=\"check(this.id, this.value)\" value=\"4\">Good<br>");
    document.write ("<input type=\"radio\" id=" + id + " name=" + radioName + 
                        " onclick=\"check(this.id, this.value)\" value=\"3\">OK<br>");
    document.write ("<input type=\"radio\" id=" + id + " name=" + radioName +
                        " onclick=\"check(this.id, this.value)\" value=\"2\">Bad<br>");
    document.write ("<input type=\"radio\" id=" + id + " name=" + radioName +
                        " onclick=\"check(this.id, this.value)\" value=\"1\">Vary Bad<br>");
}




function onSubmit() {

    // check we answered all the Questions
    for (var i = 1; i <= questionCounter; i++)
    {
        if (ans[i] == undefined)
        {
            window.alert("You forgot to answer Q:" + i);    
            return false;
        }
    }   

    return true;
}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post" method="POST">                                        
<script type="text/javascript" >                
printQueue("1.  XXX ? ");
printQueue("2.  YYY  ? ");
printQueue("3.  ZZZ  ? ");
printQueue("4.  TTT  ? ");
</script>

<br>                                    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return onSubmit()">
<br>                        
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

1. what is the right way to send (post) the results to the server:

   ```
   a. send an array with the results (array of numbers)
   b. send a structure or class with the result
   c. any other way ?
   ```
2. How can I post the result to the server ? 
   Now I'm getting `[Object, Object]` results at the server side:

   ```
   app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
      console.log("Got request: (post-res) " + res);
   })
   ```

   So how can I post the client results to the server ?

Please provide solution in Javascript/Html without Jquery use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use `$.ajax` for this purpose but since you have asked not to use jquery, so in that case you need to make XHR Request to the endpoint specified in you node application.

**Client Side**

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           console.log('request successfull : ', xmlhttp.responseText);
       }
       else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400')
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
       }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("post", "~/process_post", true);
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(..........)); //your custom data
```

**Server Side Node**

```
app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) { 
    console.log("Got request: " + res.body);
});
```

Just looking for some another question already asked on Stackoverflow, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) useful for you.

Comment: Is there a way to this with json , instead of using xml ?

Comment: i didn't get you... JSON.stringify() sends json data only... don't go by xhr's name... it support data formats apart from xml too like json, html or plain text...

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.ajax`

Suppose if your using array called sample like in below

`var sample=[1,2,3,4];`

then your ajax call should be like this

```
$.ajax({
       url: "test.html",
       data: sample,
       }).done(function(result) {

         //do the stuffs with the result here
       });
```

This call will send the sample array to test.html (as per our example)
Then the response will be stored in result variable

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: I'm not familiar with ajax. But:

why do we need to set the url value ? (the url is already defined at action tag in the <form>

Comment: Url is your server address. It can be your webservice URL or a normal server side page. Ajax is the way of sending client side data to Server as you are expected

Comment: Thanks,
My q is: Do I need to add the url in ajax, because the url is already defined at: <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post" method="POST">  ?

Comment: Please don't answer a non-jquery question with jquery. It really doesn't help.